# Python: Write a code is Legendre's equation, but maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

so, I'm writing a code to implement Legendre's equation. It works when I use the small number, but when I want to calculate P(3501,-1), it shows "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".
I have searched online resources to fix it, but I can't find the right way to fix mine.
Here's my equation:

```
def P(n,x):

     assert (type(n) is int) and (n >= 0), "n must be nonnegative integer"
     assert (x >= -1) and (x <= 1), "x must be in [-1,1]"

     if n == 0:
         return 1
     elif(n == 1):
         return x
     else: 
         return round((((2 * n)-1)*x * P(n-1, x)-(n-1)*P(n-2, x))/float(n),4)
```

And here's how I try to calculate P(3501,-1):

```
def _mode1():
  print(f"Calculated P_3501({-1.0}) = {legpoly(3501,-1)}")
```

I know it's a simple error to fix, but I just start to learn python and still don't know a lot. Please help me if you have any ideas.
Thank you!

Comment: Rounding the result at each step of the computation is a *terrible* idea. By the time all 3500 intermediate results have been computed, each one rounded off, the final result has no useful accuracy at all. If you want to print only four digits, use a format code to round off the printout.

Answer (score 0):

Short of reworking your `P` function to only require one recursive call, we can memoize the function (as half the calls are redundant) and we can expand Python's stack recursion limit:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from sys import setrecursionlimit

@lru_cache()
def P_recursive(n, x):
    if n == 0:
        return 1

    if n == 1:
        return x

    return (((2 * n) - 1) * x * P_recursive(n-1, x) - (n-1) * P_recursive(n-2, x)) / n

def P(n, x):
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0, "n must be nonnegative integer"

    assert -1 <= x <= 1, "x must be in [-1,1]"

    return P_recursive(n, x)

setrecursionlimit(10_000)

print(f"Calculated P_3501({-1.0}) = {P(3501, -1)}")
```

See if that gets you what you need.